# usb connected PNY SSD needs to be reformatted for use on XP. How to get the files to work without deleting whats on the SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have a PNY SSD that I'm connecting to my XP via usb. On first connect, a driver automatically gets installed by XP and the device gets recognized as a new hard drive. Unfortunately, when I try opening it, it asks me to reformat the whole thing.

The ssd works fine on my other computer(windows 7), but I don't have it handy right now. So is there some way to reformat the ssd and then recover the data safely?

Can someone direct me to some good free software for this?

Comment: There is absolutely no way to format it then get the data.. However your in luck if you want to get the data then format it. All joking aside what is on this drive? Is it NTFS? FAT32? And just cause I'm personally curious- why use a SSD as an external drive? (no offense use your hw however you want, just curious)

Comment: @Kyle well I recall it being FAT32. I'm only using it as an external since I'm dealing with an laptop. Also since I don't have any other means of transporting anything larger than 8gb.

Comment: @NotKylestopstalkingme Biggest reason for an external SSD is reduced power draw when used with a laptop. Whether it's enough to matter, I dunno. I haven't done an exhaustive study on the topic.